# webpack ignores .babelrc and babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack 4.32.2, and @babel/core 7.2.0

my webpack config is located here

```
projectroot/build/webpack.config.js
```

When I run my webpack config everything works fine except that my babel.config.js, which is located here

```
projectroot/babel.config.js
```

is simply being ignored.

It's the same if I use

```
projectroot/.babelrc
```

None of these files seems to matter.

Here's what the babel loader section in webpack.config.js looks like (note I've added the rootMode: 'upward' directive to make sure that any .babelrc or babel.config.js in any above directory is being found:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  options: {
    rootMode: 'upward'
  } 
}
```

I'd like to be able to use babel.config.js but if there's a problem with that I'd also go with .babelrc. At the moment neither one is being picked up by webpack.

Comment: Did you try setting the absolute path using `configFile`field ?

Comment: I can't find a configFile field in the babel-loader documentation:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Comment: `https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile`

Comment: @Easwar: Could you provide a more concrete step to set it up? By the link you provided, it's a programmatic option. So it cannot be set by `babel.config.js/json` and/or `.babelrc`. While @LongHike's intuition was right that it should be able to set via babel-loader?

Comment: @LongHike: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Easwar Unfortunately not. I've asked this question such a long time ago, I don't even remember the project I needed this answer for :-(

Answer (score 1):

My error was in package.json, i forgot to delete:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
```

babel.config.js:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";

module.exports = {
    plugins: ["react-refresh/babel"],
    presets: [
        [
            "@babel/preset-typescript",
            {
                allExtensions: true,
                allowNamespaces: true,
                isTSX: true,
                optimizeConstEnums: true,
            },
        ],
        "@babel/preset-env",
        [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            {
                // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react
                runtime: "automatic",
                pure: true,
                useBuiltIns: true,
            },
        ],
    ],
};
```